# Format a number with comma separators and round to 2 decimal places in Python 2?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm sure this must be a duplicate but I can't find a clear answer on SO.

How do I output `2083525.34561` as `2,083,525.35` in Python 2?

I know about:

```
"{0:,f}".format(2083525.34561)
```

which outputs commas but does not round. And:

```
"%.2f" % 2083525.34561
```

which rounds, but does not add commas.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Add a decimal point with number of digits `.2f` see the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language :

```
In [212]:
"{0:,.2f}".format(2083525.34561)

Out[212]:
'2,083,525.35'
```

For python 3 you can use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (thanks to @Alex F):

```
In [2]:
value = 2083525.34561
f"{value:,.2f}"


Out[2]:
'2,083,525.35'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
("%.2f" % 2083525.34561).replace(".", ",")
```

Comment: This will output `'2083525,35'` not `'2,083,525.35'`. The question is asking for a comma to be the thousands separator, not decimal separator.

Comment: Sry!! I misunderstood the question... I'm french, and in France you use decimal separator for decimals... :S

Comment: Although a mistake, your answer helped me!