# Locale-aware method to print large number with commas and decimals

Tags: python, printing

There are many well established answers for how to print numbers with commas and/or decimal places, examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626017/format-a-number-with-comma-separators-and-round-to-2-decimal-places-in-python-2), etc.

For some reason I cannot find a clear answer on how to do this for large numbers with decimals in a locale-aware way that does not force me to hard-code in the precision (e.g. when reading a file and printing values from it, no prior knowledge of how large or precise the numbers will be).

To make things more complicated I am also hoping to do this in a Python 2.7/3.x cross-compatible way.

So, if I had a number such as `1000000.01`, I would want it printed as "1,000,000.01", and `1000000.00001` as "1,000,000.00001".

Here are methods I have tried which do not work:

(using the standard [string formatter](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language))

```
# https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language
x = 1000000.01
print("{:n}".format(x)) # 1e+06 ; locale-aware but doesn't work?
print("{:g}".format(x)) # 1e+06 ; doesn't work
print("{:f}".format(x)) # 1000000.010000 ; wrong number of decimal places
print("{:,}".format(x)) # 1,000,000.01 ; desired result but not locale-aware (?)
```

based on the docs, `"{:n}"` sounds like what I want but does not seem to actually work. `"{:,}"` gives the desired result but does not seem to be locale-aware (as per the docs listed; need clarification on this).

(using `locale` [library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html))

```
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
print(locale.format("%g", x, grouping = True)) # 1e+06 ; doesn't work
print(locale.format("%d", x, grouping = True)) # 1,000,000 ; loses decimal place
# print(locale.format("%n", x, grouping = True)) # ValueError: format() must be given exactly one %char format specifier, '%n' not valid
# print(locale.format("{:n}", x, grouping = True)) # ValueError: format() must be given exactly one %char format specifier, '{:n}' not valid

print(locale.format_string("%g", x, grouping = True)) # 1e+06 ; doesn't work
# print(locale.format_string("%n", x, grouping = True)) # TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
print(locale.format_string("{:n}", x, grouping = True)) # {:n} ; not a valid formatter ?
```

It seems like `locale.format("%g", ...)` is closest to what I want but it does not appear to work correctly:

```
print(locale.format("%g", 1000.01, grouping = True)) # 1,000.01 ; works but only for small numbers
print(locale.format("%g", 10000.01, grouping = True)) # 10,000 ; doesn't work, loses decimal
```

It also seems like the `n` formatter is missing from `local.format`.

Any ideas? Seems really weird that there is no common established method for this, that I've found so far at least.

Comment: "`"{:n}"` sounds like what I want but does not seem to actually work."... I may have missed something but how doesn't it work?

Comment: `"{:n}".format(1000000.01)` returns `'1e+06'`

Comment: Sorry, how is `"{:,}"` not working?

Comment: `"{:,}"` is not locale-aware and would not work for systems where the thousands separator is `.` and not `,`. Unless I am reading the documentation wrong?

Comment: Doesn't [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators) second answer fix that?

Comment: No, `locale.format("%d", 1000000.01, grouping=True)` returns `'1,000,000'`, dropping the decimal

Comment: @user5359531 Oh, I see.

Comment: @user5359531 I have edited my answer. Does it work?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54013614/5320906

Answer (score 0):

I mean, you could split at the decimal point and compute separately. It might not be ideal but it works.

```
# `input` is your number, `output` is the formatted string.
import locale #import
sep = '.' if locale.localeconv()['thousands_sep'] == ',' else ',' #get locale sep
parts = str(input).split(sep) #get part before and after the sep
parts[0] = locale.format("%d", parts[0], grouping=True) #format **part 0**
output = sep.join(parts) #rejoin
```

I think this will do it.

The main part of importance here is the call to `locale.localeconv()['thousands_sep']`, which gets the value separator. Then, you invert it on the same line, so that a comma becomes a period and vice verca.

Comment: I may be missing something again, but plain `print("{:,}".format(x))` works for me without any more fussing required...

Comment: @Julien Are you sure? I haven't tested so I could be wrong, but I believe this is right.

Comment: **Never mind, I re-read the question and I understand now! I edited my answer to work!** *(I think... I still can't test)*

Comment: @user5359531 input is your non-formatted number, and output is the formatted string.

Comment: This solution will fail on macOS for locales where a null `thousands_sep` is specified in locale data. It will also fail on other platforms for locales where something other than `,` or `.` is used as the separator.